# Installing new Delphi and safe protecting your source codes

Tags: delphi

It is really pain to re-install windows or change the PC. Let's say we installed Delphi to a new computer. Problems we are always having are:

1. Changing default settings
2. Installing components
3. Copying source codes of our apps from other computer or disk

So do you guys doing the same or do you have any shortcut todo all these jobs for you? Also, how do you protect your source codes? Do you have any safe cloud drive to keep your source codes of your apps?

Comment: This is about three vague questions. Each one is probably off topic, and asking three at once is bad form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so your answer seems off topic for my question. Do you always downvote in your free times?

Comment: @blacksun: Users moderate this site. Your question is far too broad according to this site's guidelines. If you don't like those guidelines, you have two choices: 1) Ask at [meta] to get them changed (but make sure you research all of the dozens of previous requests that have been rejected first), or 2) feel free to ask your questions at a different site. If you're going to ask here, you're going to have to follow this site's rules. See the [help], particularly [ask].

Comment: I have asked a good question also very helpful. And the best thing you do is downvote every question. And I can understand that you have downvoted all answers.

Comment: You think it's a good question. But the voting disagrees. Perhaps you are right. Perhaps we are right.

Answer (score 2):

1) As Ian mentioned, using a virtual machine is a great idea. If you are going to make big, risky or experimental changes, you can take a snapshot first and then roll back to a known good snapshot when you're done or if anything goes wrong. It's also great for making full backups of a development environment (copy the VM folder to external storage) that can be restored to a new physical computer in the event of a failure or an upgrade. I use [VMWare Workstation](https://www.vmware.com/ca/products/workstation.html) for almost all of my development.

2) Recent versions of Delphi include a [Settings Migration Tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Settings_Migration_Tool) that lets you save all or some of your IDE settings and then import them again on the same computer or another one. I save my settings whenever I install an update, just in case.

3) Possibly the best way to protect your source code is to use source control. This lets you share the source code across development environments or between developers without having to copy files back and forth and risk having multiple, slightly different copies of your source code lying around. Of course, this is just one of the many advantages to using source control. I like [GIT](https://git-scm.com/) and possibly [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/). Delphi supports both of these in the IDE, but I like using [TortoiseGIT](https://tortoisegit.org/) or [TortoiseHG](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) to manage my repositories.

I recommend using a combination of all three approaches. It might seem a little overwhelming, but it's given me a lot of peace of mind managing multiple development projects of different customers over the course of years and several computer upgrades and a couple of hardware failures.

**Update:** Forgot to mention that source code is pushed to a local server, which is also backed up. Some people like using external cloud services (like [GitHub](https://github.com/)), but I'm a little paranoid about putting my source code on someone else's server.

Answer (score -1):

I run delphi on a virtual machine using virtualbox. Keeps all my Dev stuff separate to my other general apps.
Ian

Comment: which virtualmachine? Azure? Aws?

Comment: Locally. I run Oracle Virtualbox on my laptop. Any Delphi work is done on this away from my boot OS. It&#39;s also very easy to backup and it&#39;s all contained in a single file or two.

Comment: Well if you run it locally, what happens if you change your pc or any damage on your hdd? Do you use a cloud disk?

Comment: If I change pc I just need to install virtualbox on a new pc and copy the virtual machin hard disk to the new pc. Very quick and easy. I backup across my local network to a file server. I'd recommend installing virtualbox and having a play. It's free and very easy to use. Just remember to make sure you are licensed for the OS you install.